# How come Pyatuogui locateCenterOnScreen function find the png I want it to look for?

Tags: pyautogui

When i'm using pyautogui to be able to load an application without having to use a keyboard and mouse. The application is opening, and I want to be able to find the location of the ADF4350 option and click it. The errors read "Failed to read ADF4350.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format." The picture is in my saved pictures folder. So far I have

```
import time
import pyautogui as auto
import os

#opens ADF Software
os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Analog Devices\ADF435x\ADF435x.exe")

#finds and click on ADF4350
time.sleep(2)

ADF4350_location = auto.locateCenterOnScreen("ADF4350.png")
auto.click(ADF_location)
```

Comment: If the picture is in your "saved pictures" folder, then you need to tell the script that.  It can't read your mind.  It doesn't know where the file is located.  By the way, when using a path with backslashes, you should be using raw strings:  `r"C:\Program Files..."`.

Comment: when you have this type of error, it's always an issue with the path, you should always use the full path.

Comment: @TimRoberts using the raw string works! Thank you so much